# I need to check whether input is a number in an IF statement

Tags: c, if-statement, numbers

I'm tasked with building a house of "X"es, with the user entering the width and height of a house. One of the conditions is to check whether what they entered are numbers instead of characters. In case it is a character or something else, I'm supposed to write an error. How do I create a condition that checks the int?

I'm sure it's simple, since it's a homework for complete beginners...

Comment: Assuming that you use `scanf` to read the width and height, the return value will tell you whether `scanf` successfully read two integers.

Comment: If you are using `scanf` to read a number, it won't accept other characters. Test the return value from `scanf` to find out if it succeeded.

Comment: @user3386109 And how would I implement that return value in an IF statement? You mean ``` if (scanf("%i", integer) == 1)? ```

Comment: Yes, that's the general idea. You could have `scanf` read both integers with a single call, in which case the correct return value would be 2.

Comment: Probably should be `scanf("%i", &integer)` with that `&` meaning "address of". I would also use `%d` not `%i` unless you want to accept input in another number base.

Comment: @user3386109 Will try, thank you

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, it should... The compiler always kindly reminds me that I'm not actually that smart, every time i try to scanf, due to forgetting this.

Answer (score 3):

One of the comments did it for me:

```c
if ( scanf("%d %d", &width, &height) != 2 )
{
     fprintf( stderr, "Bad boy." );
}
```

Thank you.